# Getting different integer value from resource folder in Android

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-resources

I have a listView in my screen. I want its adapter populate 3 items if the device is small screen (320*480) while 4 items for the rest.

The way I'm doing that in adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BindableArrayAdapter<SOMETHING>
{
    private static int MAX_DISPLAYED_ITEMS;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        MyAdapter.MAX_DISPLAYED_ITEMS = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_size);
        Log.e("Test", "" + MAX_DISPLAYED_ITEMS);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return Math.min(MAX_DISPLAYED_ITEMS, super.getCount());
    }
```

and I have 2 files under `res/values-small` and `res/values-normal` one has 3 and the other 4 as value of list_size like this

```
<resources>
    <integer name="list_size">3</integer>
</resources>
```

I expect to see 3 items on [Galaxy Y](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_young_2-6480.php) (320*480) while I see 4 items.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device density is `165dpi` thats make it `mdpi` device. The resolution is `320px x 480px` and because its `mdpi` thats mean. The device is `320dp x 480dp`.

And from Google doc you can see this device is `Normal`.

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>   large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>   normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>   small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

For me I would prefer to use `sw-xxx` for example (you need to check the values):

```
res/values => 3  
res/values-sw330 => 4
```

Comment: Perfect man, you are awesome ;) I actually did values-sw but based on values-sw320 and got wrong int. Your trick fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new *.xml* file, make sure that you select the screen size under the **Available Qualifiers**. Then after that edit the information as per your needs and it should work.

I hope this helps!